# Get next "premiere" on a Youtube channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have read all the Youtube api doc but I haven't find this answer. Is there an API to know the date and time of next premiere video of a selected channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more time YouTube APIs doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/13865a43374a30611662e6e08c356de44570180b/channels.php#L84-L95) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com).
Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=upcomingEvents&id=CHANNEL_ID you will retrieve all upcoming events of the given YouTube channel.
Especially may interest you about the upcoming event:

- id: `item["videoId"]` (example: [`yVVQai84NrI`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVVQai84NrI))
- upcoming event date and time: `item["upcomingEventData"]["startTime"]` (example: `1717106417`)
- title: `item["title"]["simpleText"]` (example: `Another "Premiere" video`)
- thumbnails: `item["thumbnail"]["thumbnails"]` (example: `url`, `width`, `height`)

Channels to test:

- [Premieres](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ/videos) [`UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ) (should at least return [`BvVOl19eo1o`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvVOl19eo1o))
- [Upcoming live streams](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ/streams) [`UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ) (should at least return [`1PpAgFFP9K4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PpAgFFP9K4))

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to validate my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Français aussi ? je n'avais pas vu. Comment je la valide la réponse ?

Comment: Even if we are both French, avoid speaking French. Imagine you were looking for your original question and you only find an answer in a language that you don't know about. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) might help you to accept my answer.